# Android DOMparser couldnot get the child nodes?

Tags: android, xml, parsing, saxparser

I am parsing a xml document which contains

```
<items>
   <item> a </item>
   <item> b </item>
   .....
   <item> z </item>
</items>
```

I am able to get the items tag by

```
document.getElementsByTag("items");
```

but the problem is i couldn't get all the item tag in to a NodeList  please help ... 
Thanks in advance..

Comment: can you please post your xml here ?

Comment: Im confused. Are you using dom parser or Sax parser? document.getElementsByTag("items"); is used for dom parser.

Comment: <items imgheight="150" imgwidth="120" cols="2" maxlength="45">
  <item>
    <title>
       xyz
    </title>
    <image>
      http://www.abc.com/x.jpg
    </image>
    <description>
      something
    </description>
  </item>
  <item>
    <title>
      wxy
    </title>
    <image>
      http://www.abc.com/y.jpg
    </image>
    <description>
      something
    </description>
  </item>
  .........
</items>

Comment: @blessem : oops I confused DOM with SAX parser, actually I am using DOM parser.

Comment: @Lucifer - I have added sample xml in the comment

Answer (score 1):

than apply a loop

```
Node nodelist = Document.getElementbyTag("parent tab");

for(int i=0;i<nodelist.getlength();i++)
{
    Node node = nodeList.item(i);
    Element fstElmnt = (Element) node;
    NodeList SidList = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("sid");//the chils tags
    Element sidElement = (Element) SidList.item(0);
    SidList = sidElement.getChildNodes();
    String nameValue = ((Node) SidList.item(0)).getNodeValue();
    Log.e("Serial_id",nameValue);
}
```